# TFS 2017 Release definition. WinRM - IIS Web App Management task. Create application under "Default web site"

Tags: asp.net, iis, tfs, winrm

I am working on a release definition which will deploy a website to a test IIS server (Windows server 2012, IIS 8).

I would like to use the IIS Web App Management task to create and configure an application or virtual directory under "Default Web Site/Scott"

When I specify "Default Web Site/Scott" or "Default Web Site\Scott" as the Website, the task fails due to the name attribute.

The Scott application will be created alongside many existing applications underneath the Default Web Site parent. I don't mind if it shares the app pool.

Can I use the WinRM task? If not, are there any alternatives apart from writing Powershell?

Comment: Did you mean you want to create a web application under the website in one go through [IIS Web APP Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage)  task?

Comment: Hi Patrick. Right now I have a build definition with the following MSBuild params: /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/Scott" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination=false /p:PackageLocation=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\scott.zip

Comment: What I want to do is: 1. Create an application under Default Website called "Scott", preferably using the WinRM task. Ideally I would like to set Windows Authentication and deny Anonymous auth as well. 2. Deploy the package to the new application folder.   I can create *new* sites with WinRM, ie: as siblings of "Default Web Site" but I've had no luck creating applications as children of "Default Web site".     I've managed to populate setparameters.xml with task from Colin's ALM corner  extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [WinRM - IIS Web App Management](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions/blob/master/Extensions/IISWebAppDeploy/Src/Tasks/IISWebAppMgmt/README_IISAppMgmt.md) task,  there is also a [Parameters for IIS Application configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/iis-manage#parameters-for-iis-application-configuration) you could simply configure to deploy the IIS Web Applications. However this is not available wit TFS for now:

> The **Visual Studio Team Services** accounts that are using the
>   **preview tasks** wiz. **IIS Web Application Deployment** or **SQL Server Database Deployment**, should move to this extension. All
>   **future enhancements** to the IIS Web App Deployment task or to the SQL Server Database Deployment task will be provided in this
>   extension.
>
> *[Source Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp)*

For now you have to directly deploy a Web Application to the IIS Server with [IIS Web App Deploy](http://IIS%20Web%20App%20Deploy) task which using  Web Deploy.  You could add a environment variable `IIS Web Application Name` and use this as the website name, such as:

[image]

The “*IIS Web Application Name*” parameter is the IIS path where you want to deploy your web application. This can include a value such as `Default Web Site/Contoso.web_deploy`, this is specified in the Deploy IIS App task under *Deployment | Website Name*.

For more detail steps, you could take a look at below two nice blogs:

- [Working with Web Deploy and Release Management](https://blogs.like10.com/2016/09/08/working-with-web-deploy-and-release-management/)
- [End to End Walkthrough: Deploying Web Applications Using Team Build
  and Release Management](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/end-to-end-walkthrough-deploying-web-applications-using-team-build-and-release-management)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reply. I've already read Colins Alm Corner, that's where I learned about web.release.config and the plugin with the token substitution task. I've got the solution producing a web deploy package and tokenized setparameters.xml file nicely. The deploy to "default web site/Scott" using the WinRM task is working fine.  What is not working is the creation/configuration of web sites using the "WinRM - Web App Management" to enable Windows Auth & deny Anon.

Comment: If there is no alternative other than Powershell, I will advise the infrastructure team that they have to configure the application themselves.  Again, thanks - Scott

Comment: @Scott Enable Windows Auth & deny Anon are the future enhancements with the task only open for  the Visual Studio Team Services accounts that are using the preview tasks wiz. List in Authentication options for all configurations including three type: Anonymous authentication, Basic authentication, Windows authentication. It's not available for on-primse TFS for now.  I'm afraid you have to use powershell script to do related configuration.

Comment: Patrick, thanks again for your help! Will try powershell using "Invoke-Command" to run a script on IIS servers