# TFS 2018 Release definition. WinRM - IIS Web App Management task. Create application under “Default web site”

Tags: tfs

TFS Server : TFS 2018 Update 3

I am working on a TFS 2018 Update 3 release definition to deploy a website “MyWebSite” under “Default Web Site” on IIS server (Windows server 2012, IIS 8).

So it should be look like ServerName\Sites\Default Web Site\MyWebSite

I am using WinRM - IIS Web App Management Task. Under Website Name , I am using Default Web Site\MyWebSite

Website Name = Default Web Site\MyWebSite

I am getting the error System.Exception: ERROR ( message:Can not set attribute "name" to value "Default Web Site/MyWebSite". )

I checked this link [TFS 2017 Release definition. WinRM - IIS Web App Management task. Create application under "Default web site"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850927/tfs-2017-release-definition-winrm-iis-web-app-management-task-create-applica?rq=1) but it is for TFS 2017 and it is not working for me.

How to Fix this error? How can i have "MyWebSite" under "Default Web Site"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft added support to create virtual directories and virtual applications in version 2 (PreView) of the task. And it is working.

Comment: How did you manage to select the version 2 of the task? I can se there is a version two on github but I don't know how to make it available for selection